# How to create multiple UIButtons from a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to create a vertical list of `UIbuttons`. I have managed to create one `UIButton` in the top left corner of the screen using the following code:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
[btn setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

}
```

However when I try to increase the number the number of buttons and place them in the middle of the screen they don't appear. The code I am attempting to use is as follows:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
/* Setup your scene here */
map = [SKNode node];
midScreenX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame);
midScreenY = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame);

UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
[btn setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

for (int i = 0; i<numberOfLevels; i += 1) {

    UIButton * btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn2.frame = CGRectMake(midScreenX, midScreenY + separation*i, 100, 50);
    [btn2 setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn2];

}

}
```

I defined the variables separation and numberOfLevels outside the method with global scope as being 160 and 20 respectively.

When I use the second code, nothing changes compared to when I am using the first code.

I am very new to objective c and am probably making a very simple error. These `buttons` will obviously go off the top of the screen, increased thanks go to anyone who can tell me how to create a `scroll` effect so that I can move around the buttons. At the moment I am using very rudimentary code for that which just moves the screen around compared to where it is being touched. I imagine there are more elegant ways of doing it given its prevalence in apps.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Buttons were created into the loop so their existence is not further than the end of the loop. This is the reason that you do not see anything different i suppose.

Comment: @hoya21you are wrong, the only "problem" is that its not possible to have an access to button variables outside the scope, nothing more. Since they are added to parent view, they should be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is relatively correct, except the quite big value of `separation` and `numberOfLevels`
for i.e. iPhone 5/5s (with `568pt` screen height you should see only one button on the top left corner and two btns below the middle.

[image: this is how your screen should looks like]

this is how your screen should looks like, so the problem lies somewhere outside

to debug your views in runtime you could use small but very useful button in Xcode

[image]

more about this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: Did you change the code to get that output? I don't get that when I run my program. I get the top left hello world but not the other two.

Comment: @JackSchofield nope, just replace separation and numberOfLevels with values you provided. Again, code is correct, probably you made something wrong with view layouts

Comment: upd: @JackSchofield as another user posted here, check the values of 'midScreenX' and 'midScreenY' using breakpoint. What class contains this method?

Comment: I was using CGRectGetMidX and CGRectGetMidY on (self.frame) in order to find the middle of the screen. However, using your small and very useful button I found my buttons, which were way off screen. This is odd because the CGRect methods seemed to work previously when I put nodes on the screen. I think I will proceed by moving the buttons around manually through actual numbers rather than methods. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @JackSchofield glad to help) pls accept answer then

Comment: but returning back to question - what class contains this method? bcs instead of using self.frame you can use [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds to get screen center coordinates irrelatively to your class's frame

Comment: It is in the same class as the rest of the code, I'll try now with [UIScreen mainScreen] does that mean that UIButton and CGRect both use different coordinate systems? I notice too that with CGRect positive was up where as with UIButton positive seems to be down.

Comment: @JackSchofield no :) CGRect is a structure, that contains values for x,y,width and height and used to setup positions and frames of different UI elements (incl UIButton)

Answer (score 1):

Using Autolayout, you can checkout this code.

```
    UIButton *previousButton = nil;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i<numberOfLevels; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        [self.view addSubview:btn];

        if (i == 0)
        {
            [btn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin multiplier:1 constant:seperation]];
        }
        else
        {
            [btn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:seperation]];
        }

        [btn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:seperation]];
        [btn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:seperation]];

        [btn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:50]];

        previousButton = btn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this if it works:

```
for (int i = 0; i<numberOfLevels; i += 1) {
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setTag:i];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(midScreenX, midScreenY + separation*i, 100, 50);
    [btn setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}



- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"Button %ld clicked.", (long int)[button tag]);
}
```